# Keep getting an exception 5 [address error in store] followed by unaligned address in store. How can I fix this?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim, spim

My project requires me to enter an expression, convert it to postfix, and then be able to evaluate it. I got taking an input and converting it to an expression. However, while I'm trying push my integer into a stack in my evaluation procedure, I keep getting Exception 5 [address error in store]. I cannot figure out why it keeps giving me that exception. My assumption is that pushToStack2 is causing the issue.

```
.dataprompt1: .asciiz "Please enter an expression: "prompt2: .asciiz "\nThe expression you want to evaluate is "prompt3: .asciiz "\nThe postfix expression is "prompt4: .asciiz "\nThe evaluated answer is "userInput: .space 30postfixString: .space 30convertedString: .space 30

line: .asciiz "\n"

.text

.globl mainmain:#Calls input procedurejal input

#Calls postfix procedure
jal postfix

#Calls evaluate procedure
jal evaluation

#Calls output procedure 
#jal output

#Ends program
li $v0, 10
syscall

#Procedure to get input from user and put it into a stringinput:#Print first promptli $v0, 4la $a0, prompt1syscall

#Get user input
li $v0, 8
la $a0, userInput
la $a1, 100
syscall

#Print second prompt
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2
syscall

#Prints user input
li $v0, 4
la $a0, userInput
syscall

#Returns code back to the main procedure
jr $ra

#Procedure to change string from infix to postfixpostfix:

la $t0, userInput   # $t0 = input
la $t3, postfixString # $t3 = postfix string

li $t1, 0           # increment i
lb $t2, 0($t0)      # $t2 = character

while:
    #Loops until counter equals null
    beq $t2, $zero, endloop

    #prints the character it is on in the string - testing only
    #li $v0, 11
    #move $a0, $t2
    #syscall 

    #If character is '(', it will be pushed to stack
    beq $t2, '(', pushToStack

    #If character is an operand, it will add to postfix string
    beq $t2, '0', addToPostfixStr
    beq $t2, '1', addToPostfixStr
    beq $t2, '2', addToPostfixStr
    beq $t2, '3', addToPostfixStr
    beq $t2, '4', addToPostfixStr
    beq $t2, '5', addToPostfixStr
    beq $t2, '6', addToPostfixStr
    beq $t2, '7', addToPostfixStr
    beq $t2, '8', addToPostfixStr
    beq $t2, '9', addToPostfixStr

    #If character is an operator, it will be pushed to stack
    beq $t2, '+', pushToStack
    beq $t2, '-', pushToStack
    beq $t2, '*', pushToStack
    beq $t2, '/', pushToStack

    #If character is ')', it will be popped from stack
    beq $t2, ')', popFromStack

    #Procedure to push '(' or operator to the stack
    pushToStack:
        addi $sp, $sp, -1 #Points to next spot in stack -1 because it is a char
        sb $t2, 0($sp) #Stores charater from $t2 to where stack pointer is pointing to

        j endIteration

    #Procedure to pop from the stack
    popFromStack:
        lb $t4, 0($sp)      #Allocates space to store ')'
        addi $sp, $sp, 1    #Moves to next slot in stack

        move $t2, $t4       #Moves stored info from t4 to t2
        
        lb $t4, 0($sp)      #Allocates space to store ')'
        addi $sp, $sp, 1    #Moves to next slot in stack

        #Check if next is '(' or operator
        beq $t2, '(', addToPostfixStr
        beq $t2, '+', addToPostfixStr
        beq $t2, '-', addToPostfixStr
        beq $t2, '*', addToPostfixStr
        beq $t2, '/', addToPostfixStr

        j endIteration

    #Procedure to add characters to the postfix string
    addToPostfixStr:
        sb $t2, 0($t3)      #Saves operand or operator to the postfix string
        addi $t3, $t3, 1    #Moves to the next slot in string

        j endIteration

    #Procedure to end the current iteration
    endIteration:             
        addi $t0, $t0, 1            # $t0 = $t0 + 1
        lb $t2 0($t0)   
        j while                     #loop backs to while procedure

endloop:
    #Prints prompt 3
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt3
    syscall

    #Prints the expression after postfix
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, postfixString
    syscall

    #Skips a line
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, line
    syscall

    #Returns code back to the main procedure
    jr $ra

evaluation:

#Skips a line
li $v0, 4
la $a0, line
syscall

#Loads the postfix string
la $t0, postfixString

#Prints the expression after postfix
li $v0, 4
move $a0, $t0
syscall

 #Skips a line
li $v0, 4
la $a0, line
syscall

li $t1, 0           # increment i
lb $t2, 0($t0)      # $t2 = character

while2:
    #Loops until counter equals null
    beq $t2, $zero, endloop2

    #Prints the character from the postfix expression
    #li $v0, 11
    #move $a0, $t2
    #syscall

    #If the character is a number, it will send to the convertToInt procedure
    beq $t2, '0', convertToInt
    beq $t2, '1', convertToInt
    beq $t2, '2', convertToInt
    beq $t2, '3', convertToInt
    beq $t2, '4', convertToInt
    beq $t2, '5', convertToInt
    beq $t2, '6', convertToInt
    beq $t2, '7', convertToInt
    beq $t2, '8', convertToInt
    beq $t2, '9', convertToInt


    #beq $t2, '+', popFromStack2
    #beq $t2, '-', popFromStack2

    j endIteration2

    #Converts character to an integer
    convertToInt:

        addi $t7, $t2, -48  #Converted integer is now stored in $t4

        #Skips a line
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, line
        syscall

        #Prints the integer
        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t7
        syscall

        #Skips a line
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, line
        syscall

        #Takes integer that is stored in $t4 and pushes it into stack
        beq $t7, 0, pushToStack2
        beq $t7, 1, pushToStack2
        beq $t7, 2, pushToStack2
        beq $t7, 3, pushToStack2
        beq $t7, 4, pushToStack2
        beq $t7, 5, pushToStack2
        beq $t7, 6, pushToStack2
        beq $t7, 7, pushToStack2
        beq $t7, 8, pushToStack2
        beq $t7, 9, pushToStack2

        j endIteration2

    pushToStack2:
        addi $sp, $sp, -4 #Points to next spot in stack -4 beacuse it is an int
        sw $t7, ($sp) #Stores integer from $t4 to where stack pointer is pointing to

        #Prints the integer
        #li $v0, 1
        #move $a0, $sp
        #syscall

        j endIteration2
    

endIteration2:             
        addi $t0, $t0, 1            # $t0 = $t0 + 1
        lb $t2, 0($t0)   
        j while2                    #loop backs to while2 procedure

endloop2:

    #Returns code back to the main procedure
    jr $ra`
```

I looked around the internet and tried if .align would work but it didn't fix anything. I tried a different register in case it was already used prior.

Comment: Where is the exception occurring? What is the address that you are trying to store to? Is it aligned? You are issuing syscalls from an unaligned stack; that may also be an issue.

Comment: That error occurs on a specific machine code instruction.  It is the result of a flaw in the logic of your assembly program.  You can identify the particular machine code instruction that is causing this fault from the error message the simulator gives, and that will tell you where to begin your debugging.  The simulator will give several addresses in the error message, one for the program counter value of the machine code instruction that faults, and another for the address of the attempted data access.